Fetching online data as table in react
I'm trying to fetch this online data as table using array map, how I can do it?
import React, {useEffect, useState} from "react";
import './App.css'

function App() {
    const [data, setData] = useState([]);
    console.log(`this data before fetch: ${data}`);

    useEffect(() => {
        fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos')
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(data => setData(data))
            .catch(error => console.error(error));
    }, []);

    return (
        <div>
            <div className={"nothing"}>
                <h3>{JSON.stringify(data)}</h3>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}

export default App;

I was fetching the data as 1 object:
enter image description here
Now, I want to fetch it as table using map, can I? With detail explanation as you can,
Thanks!

Hi Muhammed Al-Ani, and welcome to SO. Yes, you can use map on your data state as it is an array of objects. I'm sure there are more than enough examples, even in the React docs themselves on how this works. If you have trouble understanding map or other loops, then make sure you learn the basics about looping first.

Thank you Emiel Zuurbier, I'll check the sites which you suggested to me
